# What are Privacy Policy and Terms and Use ?

Tags: web

well, I am going to start a new hotel listing website .
I have already build the site , But I am quit confused about the two pages contents

1. Terms of Use
2. Privacy Ppoliy

I have no idea to what to write in this.
I have follow many sites but I don't want to copy paste it from another site.

It will nice if any one tell me about these terms ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you searched yourself but take a look here:

- [Terms of Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use)
- [Privacy Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Policy)

This will tell you what they mean, so you can figure out what to write on these pages. This forum is not meant to just post something and expect others to fill in the blanks for you please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/FAQ)